# INDEX MATCH based on two criteria

Tags: excel, match

I have a list of IDs and corresponding Plans.

```
ID              Plan
123456          Ca1
456789          Ca2
456789          Ca3
34567           Ca1
67899           Ca1
67899           Ca5
```

I need to write a lookup which checks if the ID exists, and if it does, check to see if the Plan is equal to the column header, which is the plan (Ca1, Ca2, etc). If so, lookup returns 1, otherwise 0.

So, my final result will look like...

```
ID          Ca1     Ca2   Ca3   Ca5
123456      1       0      0     0
456789      0       1      1     0
34567       1       0      0     0
67899       1       0      0     1
```

My current lookup is below, where `$B$1` is the column name. However, it only works for the last ID in the list and returns 0 for the others with that specific plan.

```
=IF(INDEX([Combined.xlsx]IDs!$A:$C,MATCH($B2,[Combined.xlsx]IDs!$A:$A,0),MATCH("Plan",[Combined.xlsx]IDs!$A$1:$N$1,0))=$B$1,1,0)
```

How can I adjust my formula to return 1 for all IDs which have the specified plan? The suggested formula did not work for my desired solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index match with multiple criteria in rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469980/index-match-with-multiple-criteria-in-rows)

Comment: Use a Pivot Table not a formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner, good idea. I'll try that out next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` is the simplest solution.

[image]

Or even better with list objects:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I am not as familiar with SUMPRODUCT, can you explain how this particular implementation works?

Comment: @n8_ - it compares two matrices, when values in both of them are as specified by the variables, they return TRUE which is converted to 1 and displayed as such.  You should have no problem Googling more examples.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Rosa. Googling isn't the problem, but finding someone adept enough to explain how it works. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Countifs()` formula.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$D2,$B$2:$B$7,E$1)
```

[image]