# Excel VLOOKUP not matching multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make an expandable formula to match values from 3 columns to a table that has 4 columns, and take the 4th value of the matched row:

Table 1:

```
A    B    C

0    1    0
1    0    1   <-- matching this row
1    1    0
```

Table 2:

```
D    E    F    G

0    0    0    1
1    0    1    0.5   <-- expecting 0.5
1    1    1    1
```

And I'm using this test formula for VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2, $D$1:$G$3, 4)
```

This however returns `N/A` even though `1   0   1` exists in `Table 2`

Comment: Use `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` or If you are O365 user than use `XLOOKUP()` Function with `VLOOKUP()` you cant concatenate and use it in that way

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya I followed [this example](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/vlookup/multiple-columns) and it seems to work for them for some reason.

Comment: in the said example it worked because [Reference](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/vlookup/multiple-columns) the Lookup Value in table 2 is already concatenated where as in your example it is nt hence its not working.

Comment: All the values in Columns `D`, `E` & `G` if they are concatenated into one Column, then the `VLOOKUP()` Function shall work otherwise it wont.

Comment: So for your query the formula should be `=INDEX($G$1:$G$3,MATCH(1,(A2=$A$1:$A$3)*(B2=$B$1:$B$3)*(C2=$C$1:$C$3),0))` Or, `=XLOOKUP(1,(A2=$A$1:$A$3)*(B2=$B$1:$B$3)*(C2=$C$1:$C$3),$G$1:$G$3,"None")`

Comment: Look at this solution, [index-match-with-multiple-criteria-in-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469980/index-match-with-multiple-criteria-in-rows)

Comment: Provided options by Mayukh are the better ones, justed wanted to show that the logic you used can also be used in VLOOKUP in the following way: `=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2,CHOOSE({1,2},$D$1:$D$3&$E$1:$E$3&$F$1:$F$3,$G$1:$G$3),2,0)` note that this only if your data is always 1 character and all 3 columns are filled for all, otherwise there's the risk for false matches. Best to use the solutions from Mayukh.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya please don't answer questions in comments. That's what answers are for. The comment box even has words to that effect before you start typing.

Comment: @teylyn madam, actually, OP could have found this by little searching either in google or in Stackoverflow, just for making him understand i wrote, alright shall try to not repeat the same.